# Does a Conference Issue of a journal count the same as a journal paper in economics?

Tags: publications, journals, conference, economics

I had a working paper accepted for the Royal Economic Society which entitles people who are accepted to submit their paper for consideration for a special "Conference Issue" of the Economic Journal. On the website of the Economic Journal it states:

> Papers accepted and presented at the RES Annual Conference are
>   eligible for consideration for publication in the Conference Issue of
>   the Journal.
>
> The volume is edited by the main Editorial Board, ensuring that
>   publication standards are the same as for regular issues.
>
> Papers accepted for this year's conference volume will be published in
>   May the following year. Turn-around times are very swift. Papers are 
>   submitted in April and final decisions are made between September and
>   December.

Given the quick turn-aroud times and the prestige of the Economic Journal it would seem to be a good thing to submit it to their special Conference Issue. However, I do not know if it counts for less because it is a special Conference Issue? In which it might be better to submit to a different journal as a "general paper" (I'm thinking World Development, e.g.)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prestige of publishing in special vs regular journal issue](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20148/prestige-of-publishing-in-special-vs-regular-journal-issue).

Comment: "The volume is edited by the main Editorial Board, ensuring that publication standards are the same as for regular issues."

Comment: I'm aware of the other link, but the commenters are mostly from Computer Science and Mathematics, which have very different publishing cultures to Economics...