# What is special about the MDPI special issues?

Tags: journals, mdpi

This question is related to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13954/difference-between-special-issues-and-regular-ones), but specifically regards the special issues by [MDPI](http://www.mdpi.com/). They seem to have a quite high number of special issues for every journal per year and as far as I understand, they are only different from the regular publications by having a dedicated topic and an associated editor.

One thing that confuses me is that papers are already published before the deadlines ([this special issue with the deadline in October already has 4 papers published](http://www.mdpi.com/journal/ijgi/special_issues/Human-Computer_Interaction_GIS)).

Is there anything else that is *special* about these special issues?

Comment: When dealing with questionable publishers like MDPI (e.g., https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/is-mdpi-a-reputable-academic-publisher) never overlook the driving force of making money.

Comment: "Making money" is certainly the driving force of most publishers, even established ones.

Comment: Yup.  They are also known to plagiarise text from guest editors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There really isn't a fundamental difference between their special issues and other publishers' special issues—it's just a "themed" issue.

As for publishing papers before the deadline, that's a relative feature of digital publishing—there's no need to wait for a deadline if a paper is ready to go earlier. The collection can be "built" as papers are ready, rather than presenting everything as a single *fait accompli.*

Comment: Let me add that having papers appear as published as early as possible is a Good Thing; often you need that extra paper on your CV when you are applying for a position/grant/etc.

Comment: The special issues are a way to promote the journal. Each special issue has a guest editor. The idea is that these guest editors promote the special issue using their academic network. This is then expected to result in submissions. Personally, I ignore their requests to become guest editor.